# Merge the first column of the table

Tags: grid-layouts

I used the following code to create a table

```mathematica
beta = Quantity[9.274*10^(-24), "Joules"/"Teslas"];
Bz = Quantity[1, "Teslas"];
mlValues = {-1, 0, 1};
deltaE = beta*#*Bz & /@ mlValues;
deltaEIneV = UnitConvert[deltaE, "Joules"];

tableData = 
  Transpose[{ConstantArray[Bz, Length[mlValues]], mlValues, 
    deltaEIneV}];
tableHeader = {Style["磁场强度 Bz", Bold, 14], Style["磁量子数 ml", Bold, 14],
    Style["磁场中的分裂能 \[CapitalDelta]E", Bold, 14]};

styledTableData = Map[Style[#, 12] &, tableData, {2}];

table = Prepend[styledTableData, tableHeader];
resultTable = 
 Grid[table, Frame -> All, Alignment -> Center, 
  Background -> {None, {LightGray, {LightBlue, White}}}]
```

[image]

As you can see, the first column of the table has three identical numbers "1T". What I want to do now is to merge these three and finally achieve the following effect

[image]

I looked through the help files and found a piece of code that would help

```mathematica
Grid[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, SpanFromAbove, 6}, {7, SpanFromAbove, 9}}, 
 Frame -> All]
```

But the "2" in this one is at the top, not in the middle,`Alignment -> Center,it is useless,How should I do?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

beta = Quantity[9.274*10^(-24), "Joules"/"Teslas"];
Bz = Quantity[1, "Teslas"];
mlValues = {-1, 0, 1};
deltaE = beta*#*Bz & /@ mlValues;
deltaEIneV = UnitConvert[deltaE, "Joules"];

tableData = 
  Transpose[{ConstantArray[Bz, Length[mlValues]], mlValues, 
    deltaEIneV}];
tableHeader = {Style["磁场强度 Bz", Bold, 14], Style["磁量子数 ml", Bold, 14],
    Style["磁场中的分裂能 \[CapitalDelta]E", Bold, 14]};

styledTableData = Map[Style[#, 12] &, tableData, {2}];

table = Prepend[styledTableData, tableHeader];

table = ReplacePart[
   table, {{3, 1} -> SpanFromAbove, {4, 1} -> SpanFromAbove}];
```

For the [`Alignment`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Alignment.html), specify separate horizontal and vertical alignments.

```
resultTable = 
 Grid[table, Frame -> All, Alignment -> {Center, Center}, 
  Background -> {None, {LightGray, {LightBlue, White}}}]
```

[image]